# HttpMessageNotWritableException vs MultipleBagFetchException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm coming back to you because I'm blocked.
I'm currently facing a MultipleBagFetchException, please find bellow my Entity Expense.
To resolve this mainly the solution can be to fetch Lazy and the mistake is disappearing but at this point, my endpoint findAll() is not working, because fetches should be EAGER for this endpoint being able to work.

In other words, on both side, I'm blocked.
Impossible for me to change List for Set as it's totally against "my business need".

If anyone is having any idea how can I fix this... :(

Thank you very much guys.

Rgds,
Erick

```
package net.erickcaron.mybudgetapi.models;

import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name="expenses")
public class Expense {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="total_amount")
    private BigDecimal totalAmount;

    @Column(name="shared_amount")
    private BigDecimal sharedAmount;

    @Column(name="personal_amount")
    private BigDecimal personalAmount;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Shop shop;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Currency currency;
}
```

```
package net.erickcaron.mybudgetapi.rest;

import net.erickcaron.mybudgetapi.exceptions.IncorrectResourceInputException;
import net.erickcaron.mybudgetapi.models.Expense;
import net.erickcaron.mybudgetapi.services.CurrencyService;
import net.erickcaron.mybudgetapi.services.ExpenseService;
import net.erickcaron.mybudgetapi.services.ShopService;
import net.erickcaron.mybudgetapi.utils.Checkings;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class ExpenseController {

    @Autowired
    private ExpenseService expenseService;

    @Autowired
    private ShopService shopService;

    @Autowired
    private CurrencyService currencyService;

    @PostMapping("shops/{shopId}/currencies/{currencyId}/expenses")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Long create(@PathVariable("shopId") Long shopId, @PathVariable("currencyId") Long currencyId, @RequestBody Expense expense) {
        Checkings.checkFoundShop(shopService.findById(shopId));
        Checkings.checkFoundCurrency(currencyService.findById(currencyId));
        checkExpenseCalculation(expense);
        return expenseService.create(shopId, currencyId, expense);

    }

    @GetMapping("/expenses")
    public List<Expense> findAll() {
        return expenseService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/shops/{shopId}/expenses")
    public List<Expense> findAllByShopId(@PathVariable("shopId") Long shopId) {
        Checkings.checkFoundShop(shopService.findById(shopId));
        return expenseService.findAllByShopId(shopId);
    }

    @GetMapping("/expenses/{id}")
    public Expense findById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        Checkings.checkFoundExpense(expenseService.findById(id));
        return expenseService.findById(id).get();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/expenses/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        Checkings.checkFoundExpense(expenseService.findById(id));
        expenseService.delete(expenseService.findById(id).get());
    }

    @PutMapping("/shops/{shopId}/expenses/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void update(@PathVariable("shopId") Long shopId, @PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Expense expense) {
        Checkings.checkFoundExpense(expenseService.findById(id));
        Checkings.checkFoundShop(shopService.findById(shopId));
        checkExpenseCalculation(expense);
        expenseService.update(id, expense);
    }

    @PatchMapping("/expenses/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void partialUpdate(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Expense expense) {
        Checkings.checkFoundExpense(expenseService.findById(id));
        checkExpenseCalculation(expense);
        Expense expenseToUpdate = expenseService.instancingExpense(expenseService.findById(id).get(), expense);
        expenseService.update(id, expenseToUpdate);

    }


    private void checkExpenseCalculation(Expense expense) {
        if (!expenseService.checkIfExpenseCalculationIsCorrect(expense)) {
            throw new IncorrectResourceInputException();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `Expense` entity you posted, your `Shop` and/or `Currency` entities probably have `List` *-to-many associations that you try to fetch with `FetchType.EAGER`. Based on this root entity, all associations reachable through some kind of `EAGER` attribute are considered and it is an error if there is more than 1 `List` *-to-many association.

What you can do is simply switch to the more logical type `Set` which doesn't have that problem or use `LAZY` which you probably also should do. You can control fetching in a fine grained manner by using entity graphs or join fetch in HQL queries.

Comment: The option HQL query is I think the best as I can not use Set